# fgetcsv returning NULL in PHP 4

Tags: php, php4

One of our systems is running on PHP 4 and no I can't change that.

The `fgetcsv` function seems to return null no matter what file I upload.

Very simply put:

```
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
var_dump(fgetcsv($handle));
fclose($handle);
```

This will print out "NULL".

Doing var_dump on the $handle object does give me a resource:

```
resource(33) of type (stream)
```

But I just get NULL when using fgetcsv

I can get the contents of the file using `file_get_contents`, but then it's more awkawrd to parse it as a csv.

As I say, I can't really do anything about it being on PHP 4. Does anyone know what might be causing this, or shall I find another way?

Thanks

Comment: _"fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied"_

Comment: Yes, but the handle is valid.

Comment: Yeah, dunno, that's all I got heh. Maybe PHP4 can't `var_dump()` something that's not actually a var? Assign the return value to a var first?

Comment: What is $file? Is it some url?

Comment: It's an uploaded file.

Comment: What specific version of PHP 4?

Comment: 4.4.9. I'm trying to do it with file_get_contents at the moment, but it seems even running the trim() function on some strings is too much for the server, times out after 60 seconds. Not quite sure why its struggling so much to trim some whitespace

Comment: "asked 32 mins ago".....PHP 4 has been out of support for 10 years.

Comment: @symcbean welcome to the education industry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original issue may be related to temporary uploaded file usage.
Try to open it **after** [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Also, `fseek($handle, 0)` can help theoretically, because it was read already anywhere.

---

> I can get the contents of the file using `file_get_contents`

You can try to use [tmpfile](http://php.net/tmpfile) then:

```
$csv = file_get_contents($file);
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $csv);
fseek($temp, 0); // prepare for read at start
$data = fgetcsv($temp);
fclose($temp); // file autoremoved here
```

Comment: `str_getcsv()` is not available in PHP4.

Comment: Ooops) Didn't know that

Comment: What issue is there with "temporary uploaded file usage"? Manual, specs, citations?

Comment: Aha, that seems to have worked, although i had to add in a length parameter to fgetcsv(). Thjanks